# Does declaring unused linked uniform consume memory/performance?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

Let's say I have a `foo` uniform linked to a shader program and actually used in the vertex shader:

```c
uniform sampler2D foo;

...
```

What if I declare the same uniform `uniform sampler2D foo;` in the fragment shader BUT I don't use it at all. Does that declaration (of an unused uniform) consume memory or performances? Or is it totally ignored by ALL compilers/interpreters?

The uniform is active for the vertex shader but NOT for the fragment shader, so that https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Active_uniforms does not help me answering my question.

---

A little bit of context: I'm asking this question because I'm creating an OpenGL shader program library that help the developper creating GLSL and handles uniform variable declaration and binding for him.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, for directly-set uniforms like this it should be fine. I'd expect any compiler to strip unused uniforms when doing code generation.

You may get some small penalty (e.g. cache pressure) for unused data in uniform buffer objects, but likely to be tiny unless you are doing something daft.

> Or is it totally ignored by ALL compilers/interpreters?

However, it's impossible to guarantee this without testing all compilers. It's entirely implementation-defined behavior.